# How make it display the entire contents of the normal when use xhtml2pdf?

Tags: python, html, css, pdf, xhtml2pdf

When the contents of the *<p>* paragraphs in the html code are too long,
How can I make it display the entire contents of the normal? 
**No artificial add tags,eg: *<br>***. I tried to use css to limit the maximum 
length, and automatic word wrap, but it still can not.

test case:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import xhtml2pdf.pisa as pisa

pisa.showLogging()

def dumpErrors(pdf, showLog=True):
if pdf.warn:
        print "*** %d WARNINGS OCCURED" % pdf.warn
    if pdf.err:
        print "*** %d ERRORS OCCURED" % pdf.err

def testlong(src="example.html", dest="example.pdf"):
    pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(file(src, "r"), file(dest, "wb"))

    dumpErrors(pdf)
    if not pdf.err:
        pisa.startViewer(dest)

if __name__=="__main__":
    testlong()
```

the example html code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
        <style>
            body{
                font-family: 'Gilles';
            }
            .testdiv {
                width:100%;
                max-width:500px;
                word-break:break-all;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="testdiv">
            <p>
 "sdfsdfsdfffffffffffffffffffffffffffwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwggggggggggggggggggggggggpppppppppppaaaaaaazzzzzzzzzzxxxxxxxccccccvvvvvvvbbbbnnnnnnnnmmmmmkkkkkkkkllllll"
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

the PDF:
    [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF6Dl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this [pdfkit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit)

Install this also [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_file('example.html', 'example.pdf')
```